# APA: Paper in past tense but is/was verb confusion for alive author

Tags: grammar, verbs, american-english, tenses, syntactic-analysis

I want to state, "One advocate for the issues based teaching style is/was Brian Schultz."

He is alive, but my paper is in past tense. What do I do?

Comment: I think the answer depends on context, which you haven't given us.

Comment: I am writing a paper about the purpose of social studies education. I have to use 5 sources. In my paper, when I quote, I am using "wrote/stated/said/ etc." all past tense. I read that you should use past tense or present perfect tense. So I tried to write, "One author who has advocated for the issues based teaching style is/was Brian Schultz." So I am using the present perfect tense, but now do I use is/was? Does that help?

Comment: I'd use *is* there, but let's see what other people say. There's nothing wrong with switching tenses if you have a reason to.

Comment: You ask about, "One author who has advocated for the issues based teaching style is/was Brian Schultz."  Note that the *present* perfect  matches up with the *present* tense so it must be 'is'.  So, "who **has** advocated... **is** Brian Schultz"

Comment: ' ... my paper is in past tense' is a rather draconian statement. Do you mean '... uses largely past tenses'?

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Shor notes in his comment, the answer will depend crucially on the context of your sentence, which will identify the time span you're talking about.

If you're narrating history from the present point of view or if you're talking about a specific time past, use the **simple past**.  As an example of the latter:

> Brian Schultz **was** an advocate for an issues-based teaching style
>   during the early years of its development.

If your narrative includes present events of if you don't have a specific past time, then the simple past will imply that Brian Schultz used to be an advocate but he's not any more.

If you're talking about a time span before a specific past event, use the **past perfect**:

> Even before issues-based teaching became a popular topic in the
>   journals, Brian Schultz **had been** an advocate of its style.

If you're talking about an indefinite past time span that extends to the present moment use the **present perfect**:

> Brian Schultz **has been** a long-time advocate of the issue-based
>   teaching style.

Notice phrasing this directly with BS as the subject is not only stronger than "an author who has advocated is/was" but it gets rid of the need to worry about the extra verb.  (Better still would be "BS has advocated," but I kept the form of *to be*.)

If you wish to emphasize the continuing contribution of Brian Schultz, use the present perfect progressive:

> Brian Schultz **has been advocating** the issue-based
>   teaching style for a long time.

If BS currently supports issue-based teaching style, then use the **simple present**:

> Brian Schultz *is* an advocate of the issue-based teaching style.

If you wish to emphasize the current contributions of BS, which are a continuation of his ongoing support, use *other word*s to give the **simple present** an enduring sense of then, now, and to come:

> Brian Schultz **is** a *long-time* advocate of the issue-based
>   teaching style.

If you wish to emphasize the continuing and current state of affairs with regard to BS, use the **present progressive**:

> Brian Schultz **is advocating** the issue-based teaching style.

This will cover a short time in the past, right now, and an expected time in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You could try other ways of expressing your point that would keep the sentence in past or past-perfect tense, like "Brian Schultz has been an advocate for the issues-based teaching style," or "Brian Schlutz advocated the issues-based teaching style in his work ____."